# Breakout Game erasing rectangles pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a breakout game using the pygame module, and I've established most of the functionalities. However, I'm having a hard time making the ball collide with the blocks at the top of the screen. Specifically in the "collisions" method in the main class. I wrote a for loop to iterate through the block list to check if the block collided with the ball, and if it did, then it would remove from the row_1 list the respective index of the block, theoretically erasing the block from the screen. But I get an AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'collidirect'. I appreciate the help.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 750

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
purple = (138, 43, 226)
red = (255, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Breakout Game")

class BLOCK:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 54
        self.height = 20
        self.row_1 = [[5, 20]]
        self.blocks = []

        for i in range(9):
            self.row_1.append(self.row_1[-1][:])
            self.row_1[-1][0] += 59

    def draw_blocks(self):
        for cor in self.row_1:
            block_rect = pygame.Rect(cor[0], cor[1], self.width, self.height)
            self.blocks.append(block_rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, block_rect)

class BALL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 15
        self.height = 15
        self.x = screen_width/2 - self.width/2
        self.y = screen_height/2 - self.height/2
        self.speed_x = 5
        self.speed_y = 5
        self.ball_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    def draw_ball(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, white, self.ball_rect)
    def move_ball(self):
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += self.speed_y
        self.ball_rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
    def wall_collision(self):
        if self.x >= screen_width - self.width:
            self.speed_x *= -1
        if self.x <= 0:
            self.speed_x *= -1
        if self.y >= screen_height - self.height:
            self.x = screen_width/2 - self.width/2
            self.y = screen_height / 2 - self.height/2
        if self.y <= 0:
            self.speed_y *= -1

class PADDLE:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 10
        self.x = screen_width/2 - self.width/2
        self.y = 600
        self.speed = 7
        self.paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    def draw_paddle(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, purple, self.paddle_rect)
    def move_paddle(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.speed

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.speed

        self.paddle_rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)

class MAIN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.block = BLOCK()
        self.ball = BALL()
        self.paddle = PADDLE()
    def draw(self):
        self.block.draw_blocks()
        self.ball.draw_ball()
        self.paddle.draw_paddle()
    def move(self):
        self.ball.move_ball()
        self.paddle.move_paddle()
    def collisions(self):
        self.ball.wall_collision()
        if self.ball.ball_rect.colliderect(self.paddle.paddle_rect):
            self.ball.speed_y *= -1

        for block in self.block.blocks:
            if block.collidirect(self.ball.ball_rect):
                self.block.row_1.pop(self.block.blocks.index(block))

main = MAIN()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)
    main.draw()
    main.move()
    main.collisions()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo.  The name of the method is [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) rather then `collidirect`:

<s>`if block.collidirect(self.ball.ball_rect):`</s>

```py
if block.colliderect(self.ball.ball_rect):
```

Comment: Thank you. That was actually the problem. But now I'm getting an IndexError: pop index out of range. I think I know what the issue is but I don't know how to fix it..